# Open first JavaScript accordion

Tags: javascript, accordion

How to open the first in a JavaScript accordion? It's a basic accordion with `+` for opening and `-` for closing. I'm new to this and I'm only finding solutions for jQuery accordions. Also would like to know if jQuery is the way to go when it comes to accordions?

Here's the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dmkx8hg0/

Here's the code:

```
<head>
<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>content</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>content</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>content</p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: whats wrong in using Jquery.... ??

Comment: The code I'm working with is javascript. Hence continued on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just trigger the click event for the first element in your javascript.  [Here's an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmkx8hg0/6/).

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
acc[0].onclick();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add active classname and style to your panel, it should do the trick if you want the first panel to open.

`<button class="accordion active">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel" style="max-height: 89px;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>`